# Update google contact photo with People API using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I want to update a contact photo of my contacts using People API and google apps script. official document URL is here https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContactPhoto

My Google Apps script code is below

```
function imageUpdate(){
  var id = 'c6379259805458445151'
  var url = 'https://admin.singlaapparels.com/Main/fileurl/64F619B8-C2BE-4EDF-BF9B-01FD60C5D957/4/RakeshKumar.jpg'
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  var data = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(blob.getBytes());
  var resourceName = 'people/'+id;
  Logger.log(data)
  var reqBody = {
    "photoBytes": data,
    "personFields": "photos"
  }
var res = People.People.updateContactPhoto(resourceName, reqBody)
Logger.log(res)   
}
```

I got this error:  API call to people.people.updateContactPhoto failed with error: Empty response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change the position of parameters and It works for me.

**from**

```
var res = People.People.updateContactPhoto(resourceName, reqBody)
```

**to**

```
var res = People.People.updateContactPhoto(reqBody, resourceName)
```